# Passing custom environment variables into dockerized react-admin app

Tags: reactjs, docker, react-admin

I'm using [react-admin](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin) in a project which shall run in a Docker swarm.

As we have multiple environments I defined an environment variable `REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT` which points to our application's API with which react-admin shall interact.

So far I have learned that this variable must be "baked into react-admin" on build time. So I added the following to my `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT
ENV REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT $REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT
```

If this is true are my following assumptions correct?

- I must set the value for `REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT` when *running the `docker build` command*.
- I will need one Docker image per environment.

Or is there a more feasible and dynamic way to pass that variable to react-admin?

Comment: Probably you need one container per environment, not one image. The common image can be used to create many containers configured with propagated environment variable `REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT`. And this part can be done at the moment of creating containers, not on creating images. Of course it can be done earlier, and later on overwritten by running process. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables

Comment: The post has been edited... yes - base on your source image, all before entrypoint you can adjust during build process

Answer (score 0):

  1.

`dockerfile`

`ARG REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT`

`docker build --build-arg REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=192.168.0.1`

2. You will need build container per environment

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working.

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT
ENV REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT $REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT
```

Then, to build the container:
`docker build -t myimage --build-arg REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=<URL> .`

It looks a bit weird to me but I couldn't figure out any other way as React does need custom variables like `REACT_APP_MY_VARIABLE` at build time.

Answer (score 0):

At start i thought passing environment variables in a docker-compose file will work, but using `RUN printenv` inside Dockerfile (which prints systems environment variables), i found that the variables i was passing in, were not available when React was building production files.
The key here is to pass environment variables inside Dockerfile, when the image is created, before React build files are created.
Hence, a Dockerfile like this should work:

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
#declaring react custom environment variable
ENV REACT_APP_API_HOST http://localhost:8080
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci --silent
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build
```